# I want to assign a record to TStringList.Objects

Tags: delphi

I want create a Playlist control. I have a lot of information to display into a TStringList. I want to assign a record to TStringGrid.Objects instead of an object because so many objects may take a while to create/destroy. It also take a lot of RAM.

A record will be much faster and slim. 
How can I do that?

```
TYPE
 AMyRec= packed record
        FullName     : string[255];    
        RelativePath : boolean;        
        IsInvalid    : boolean;        
        InCache      : boolean;        
        etc
       end;
```

Comment: How are you creating your records? Using New(PMyRec) will take a similar amount of time (or any other method that creates them on the heap)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a TList to a Pointer of your record.

Eg:

```
Type    
PMyrec = ^AMyRec;
```

usage

```
var
   MyRec : PMyRec;
new(MyRec);
MyRec^.Fullname := 'test';
MyRec^.RelativePath := false;
```

etc

{ MyList is a List you have create elsewhere }

```
MyList.Add(MyRec);
```

You'll have to handle disposing of items from the list eg

`Dispose(PMyRec(MyList[Index]));`

To use an item from the list:

```
var
  MyRec : PMyRec;

PMyRec := MyList.Items[i];
txtBox.Text = PMyRec^.Fullname;
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

you can using the record Pointer.

```
List.AddObject(MyRecord.FullName, @MyRecord);
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. The record is bigger than four bytes. Square peg, round hole.

Comment: Yes you can. Every Tlist has a 4-byte Object you can use for any purpose. You can allocate your record and set this object as a pointer to the record so you can easily find it. 

So this is the correct answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to make sure you put the record on the heap instead of the stack?  If it is on the stack then it will be stale when it goes out of scope.

Comment: That would be @MyRecord and would not work outside of the method since the record is tack based.

Comment: This will not work, because a record is not an object and not a pointer either. You would have to make sure the record is stored on the heap and assign a pointer to it to the list.

Comment: Thomas, you can becouse you can add the pointer to the record, and is what I usually do.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**
I have tried something like this now (based on KiwiBastard's example):

```
Type
 AMyRec= packed record
        FullName     : string[255];
        RelativePath : boolean;
        IsInvalid    : boolean;
       end;
 PMyrec = ^AMyRec;

procedure TPlaylst.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR MyRec1: PMyRec;
    PlaylistCtrl: TStringGrid;
begin
 {SET}
 new(MyRec1);
 MyRec1^.Fullname := 'test';
 MyRec1^.RelativePath := false;
 PlaylistCtrl.Objects[1,1]:= Pointer(MyRec1); 


 {GET}
 ...
end;
```

---

Comment: Again, just do a typecast: PlaylistCtrl.Objects[1,1]:= Pointer(MyRec1); and the reverse to get the data back out: MyRec := TMyRec(PlaylistCtrl.Objects[1,1]);

Comment: An object is four bytes larger than the corresponding record. And Mike's second type-cast should be to PMyRec, not TMyRec.

Comment: So, using records instead of objects will "eat" about the same amount of RAM?

Comment: you really should edit the original or create a new question.  The correct answer to the original question has already been given.  Stack Overflow works best when its single question, all possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are willing to allocate all those objects? By the look on the record structure it looks like you want an object per row - not per cell. To do that you have at least 2 options:

1. (My favorite because of the freedom it gives) You use TDrawGrid instead and draw the content of your cell manually. It's really not that hard!
2. You make an object that encapsulates this record. It's an easy one as well, like for example:

```
type
  TMyRec= packed record
    FullName     : string[255];
    RelativePath : boolean;
    IsInvalid    : boolean;
  end;
  TMyData = object (TObject)
  private
    FData: TMRec;
  public
    constructor Create(AData: TMyRec);
    property FullName: String read FData.FullName write FData.FullName;
    property RelativePath: Boolean read FData.RelativePath write FData.RelativePath;
    property IsInvalid: Boolean read FData.IsInvalid write FData.IsInvalid;
  end;

...

constructor TMyData.Create(AData: TMyRec);
begin
  FData := AData;
end;
```

Now whenever you want to hook up your data to the grid you just pack it into that object and you can then use the Objects collection.

Now instead of going through all that hassle just create an event handler for TDrawGrid.DrawCell like

```
procedure TMainForm.GrdPathsDrawCell(Sender: Object; ...);
```

use GrdPaths.Canvas.Handle with DrawText or if Unicode is needed use DrawTextW (both come from Windows API so there's tons of examples of how to use it) and you'll save you and your client a lot of frustration, memory and above all - time.

Answer (score 0):

allocate the memory for the records takes also time.

create your record and put the pointer to the objects in stringlist.