# Need a name=value class similar to TStringList but the value part is variant

Tags: delphi

I need a class similar to TStringList that could manage name & value pairs, but the value part is variant. Or perhaps it has a property like TStringList.Object but holds variants instead of objects.

Could anyone please point me to a free or open source implementation? I use Delphi 7.

Thank you.

Comment: What Delphi version are you using? D2009 and up has the generic TDictionary class which you can use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PVariantRec = ^TVariantRec;
TVariantRec = record
  Value : Variant;
end;

var
  lItem : PVariantRec;
  lMyStringList : TStringList;

lMyStringList := TStringList.Create;
lMyStringList.Sorted := true;
lMyStringList.OwnObjects := false;

//add
New(lItem);
lItem.Value := 'zzz';
lMyStringList.Add('name', TObject(lItem));

//remove
lItem := PVariantRec( lMyStringList.Objects[0] );
Dispose(lItem);
lMyStringList.Delete(0);
```

Comment: Is it safe to do TObject(lItem) ?

Comment: Yes, its safe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367130/i-want-to-assign-a-record-to-tstringlist-objects

Answer (score 4):

You have not given the Delphi version this is intended to be used with, but starting with Delphi 2009 you can use a `TDictionary<string, Variant>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Delphi 2009 or 2010, you can use the `TStringList<T>` class in [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/) to create a `TStringList<Variant>`. (You could also use TDictionary, but TStringList has a lot of extra functionality that you might not want to lose.)

Answer (score 3):

You can derive from TStringList and use the Objects property to hold a wrapper object for a variant.